# Hide a popup div on ESC key press with Javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, dom-events

```js
//Function To Display Popup
function div_show(x) {
document.getElementById(x).style.display = "block";
div_hide(x);
}
//Function to Hide Popup
function div_hide(x){
            
window.onkeyup = function (event){           
    if(event.keyCode == 27)
    document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none"};
}
```

I want to hide the popup I created, but the `div_hide` function doesn't work. I even tried an alert message and it results that the event `keycode` is undefined. Basically I can't catch the <kbd>esc</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass `event` as an argument. You will still be able to use `event.keyCode` inside your event handler.